# /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx throws 404 errors but site still works fine

Tags: kentico

I have a situation here, on iis logs I see the /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx causing 404 errors but the requests are still fulfilled.

The question that I have is how do I stop these 404 errors from being logged since the website still works. I only want to see the real 404 erros which occur when the request URL is invalid

I am using the Portal Engine approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IIS log, find out what the parameters after the `/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx` causing the 404.  You may be able to see these 404 errors in the Kentico Event Log as well.  The majority of the requests to deliver page content goes through the `/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx` page which is why you're seeing it in the IIS logs.

Once you find the record which has the 404 info, you should be able to find the path to the file and resolve it.

Comment: Thank you, I went to the event logs and noticed that there was an image that was not being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check your network tab in your favorite browser. Usually there is a favicon or woff font not being served.

Comment: There was an image that was not loaded correctly, thanks, you've also helped a lot.